# Fibonacci in linear time by using an extra pointer

Tags: swift, recursion, fibonacci

I have a function to find the nth number in a fibonacci sequence, in which I am recursively calling the function. The sum is stored in a class variable and I have an extra pointer I increment every time the function gets called. This extra pointer is the gate keeper which dictates the base case of when to exit from the loop. The performance I get, using this algorithm is, O(n) linear time and with O(1) space. I get the expected answer but I am confused if this an acceptable solution from a coding interview stand point.

```
var x = 0
var sum = 0
func myFibonacci(of n: Int, a: Int, b:Int) -> Int {
  x+=1
  if (x == n) {
    return sum
  } else {
    sum = a+b
    return myFibonacci(of: n, a: b, b: sum)
  }
}

let finalAns = myFibonacci(of: 9, a: 0, b: 1)
print("The nth number in Fibonacci sequence is \(finalAns)")
```

Output: 34

Time complexity: O(n) linear time

Space complexity O(1)

Is this an acceptable solution for a coding interview?

Comment: If your code works as expected and you are asking for a *review* then you should post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Actually your solution does *not* work. Calling `myFibonacci()` a second time will give a wrong result or cause a crash. Try `print(myFibonacci(of: 9, a: 0, b: 1)); print(myFibonacci(of: 9, a: 0, b: 1))`

Comment: Appreciate your response. Yes that's correct, it will crash, because I have to reset the values of x and sum, since they are global mutable variables. When writing this algorithm on a white board, is this something we have to take into consideration? I am trying this on a playground, so never really thought about this use case.

Comment: Please have a look at my first comment. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/196432 about what site to post on, in particular Stack Overflow vs Code Review. As written currently ("Is this an acceptable solution") is looks more like a request for a review.

Comment: yes thank you! Have posted this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183768/fibonacci-in-linear-time-by-using-an-extra-pointer